# Move columns to the right in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataset:

| Stop_ID | On_Demand | Tarif | Heading |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T100 | Station |  |
| 2 | DYes | T101 | Gym |
| 3 | T101 | River |  |

I want to have:

| Stop_ID | On_Demand | Tarif | Heading |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DNo | T100 | Station |
| 2 | DYes | T101 | Gym |
| 3 | DNo | T101 | River |

I tried:

```
for index, row in sm.iterrows():
    if not row["On_Demand"].startswith("D"):
        sm.loc[index, "Tarif":] = row["On_Demand":]
        sm.loc[index, "On_Demand"] = "DNo"
```

but it doesnt bring any result. Any idea how can I achieve it?

Comment: try `sm.at[index,'Tarif'] = row['On_Demand']` that is inplace of loc try if at solves the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) with `axis=1` only filtered rows by inverted mask by `~` and then set column `On_Demand` by same mask:

```
m = df["On_Demand"].str.startswith("D")

df.loc[~m, "On_Demand":] = df.loc[~m, "On_Demand":].shift(axis=1)
df.loc[~m, "On_Demand"] = "DNo"

print (df)
   Stop_ID On_Demand Tarif  Heading
0        1       DNo  T100  Station
1        2      DYes  T101      Gym
2        3       DNo  T101    River
```